# interesting tags colour is horrible

Tags: feature-request, tag-watching

I would like a way to change the colour of the highlighting of questions for interesting tags on stackoverflow.com. The orange colour currently in use is really horrible.

Comment: They are blue now, what are you talking about?

Comment: I am talking about the highlighting of questions on stackoverflow.com.

Comment: The orange color matches the orange-ish color scheme of Stack Overflow. It would make more sense for them to allow registered users to select different color schemes. The orange color isn't the most attractive color, but a blue would look terrible because of how badly it would stick out.

Comment: Looking at the original question I can see how it was misunderstood. The request I am making is for the ability to change the colour for me personally.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty certain it's all CSS (too lazy to open source at 2:30am) so you can use FireFox and one of the Add-Ons that allow you to change the CSS (I'm certain Web Developer lets you but there must be something more lightweight :)

Comment: I have barely used Firefox since Google Chrome came out.

Comment: I tried Chrome when it JUST came out. Was **severely** underwhelmed by supposedly fast JS engine (the main reason I got it was to see if I could make a very slow JS coprorate app run faster without a re-write :) ). I assume it's better now but have no clue if it got up to its promised JS speed nor whether it has any worthy FF-like add-ons.

Comment: Firefox Developer Edition is faster.